# MongoDB + Node.js collection.find({}).toArray() not returning

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const tokenValidation = require("../tokenValidation");
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId;
const client = new MongoClient(process.env.DB_CONNECT);
const posts = client.db("TestDb").collection("posts");

router.get("/", tokenValidation.authToken, async (req, res) => {
  const test = await posts.find({}).toArray();
  console.log(test);
  res.json(test).send();
});
```

**
error: MongoNetworkError: Socket connection timeout
Does'nt return anything, if i use findOne with a query, insertOne, everything works
**

Comment: It looks like you are retrieving the entire collection and trying to load it all in memory at the app. Is that on purpose? If so, that process is going to take time and be resource intensive, requiring more as the collection grows

Comment: Yes, it has just 2 documents in collection, but i see that even with a query in the find function still not works